How to deserialize Double in Jackson ObjectMapper without scientific notation
I have a model stored in the database as a JsonNode and I need to deserialize it into my DTO. However, when I deserialize double values, they are presented in scientific notation, like this: "doubleField": 1.25996789E9.
I've attempted to address this by configuring my ObjectMapper with objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS, true), but this didn't yield the desired result.
I also tried creating a custom JsonDeserializer and registering it as a simple module, but this approach returns a double value when I actually need a formatted value without scientific notation.
Two options currently work for me:

Changing the type to BigDecimal.
Adding an annotation for each field with @JsonDeserialize(using=MyDoubleDeserializer.class).

However, I'm not satisfied with either option. I want to apply this setting at the ObjectMapper configuration level. Can you guide me on how to achieve this correctly?

When you deserialize a double, you just get a double. It isn't in any notation, just in the internal IEEE binary format. Do you mean when you serialize doubles?
